# Covariant return types while overriding methods and `List<T>' vs 'List<? extends T>'

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Intuitively (and wrongly) I think that `List<T>` is not more specialized than `List<? extends T>` so below shall not compile (because *return type covariance* mandates that return type in Derived is same or subtype of that in Base) - but it compiles! I (wrongly) would expect it to compile if we change places of the methods.

But what is the strict (and correct) reasoning why this works?

```
class Base {
    <T> List<? extends T>  f1() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

    <T> List<T>  f1() {   // fine !!! Not compile error.
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Besides I misunderstand something - both methods have `<T>` - so could those two T's ever be different `T` ?

Comment: Type erasure in generics makes this impossible.

Comment: This looks like a bug (or a hole) in the compiler spec to me.  I don't think it should be possible to declare a different type of list in `Derived`.  Well, the type of list returned by `Derived` is more permissive, but it's still a `List`, so maybe the spec says this is compatible enough and permits it?

Comment: @markspace but `List<T>` _is_ a subtype of `List<? extends T>` - this is perfectly legit.

Answer (score 1):

Why would this not compile? `List<T>` *is* a sub-type of `List<? extends T>`, i.e. this compiles just fine:

```
List<String> one = List.of("one");
List<? extends String> two = one;
```

It is also said that a wildcard with a bounded type, makes the type covariant.